# How can I set the default font to a JavaFX HTMLEditor

Tags: fonts, javafx-8

I set Text to my HTMLEditor and by default it is in "Times New Roman". But when I start typing at the beginning of the loaded text it is the font of the HTMLEditor "Segoe UI".

[image: screenshot Example of the wrong font]

**How can I set the same font to the complete text?**

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue that actually seems to work. If you set the font using HTML passed to setHTMLText(), for example just after the body tag, it will work:

```
HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
String htmlRoot = "<body><font face=\"Times New Roman\"></font face></body></html>";
htmlEditor.setHtmlText(htmlRoot);
```

Comment: The bottom snippet only changes the UI font.

Comment: It didn't work for me. The font in edition area did not changed and the  combobox does not showed the font name.